# Alinhamento de texto no sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Como posso deixar alinhar este texto de acordo com a tela?

Como coloco uma quebra de linha pelo Share Point Designer?

[image: Print]

Answer (score 1):

Pelo Sharepoint Designer acesse o site, aonde se encontra a sua lista, depois navegue até:
`/Lists/{Nome da Lista}/DispForm.aspx`

Edite o arquivo em modo avançando, depois adicione o seguinte código:

```
.ms-pagetitle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Tem que ser logo abaixo do código: `.ms-bodyareaframe`